# How to force jshint to print source file where the the hint applies?

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I am running jshint from grunt.
Here is my config:

```
jshint: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'app/htmlplayer/js/directives/**/*.js'],
    options: {
        globals: {
            jQuery: true
        }
    }
},
```

But after running `grunt test` which triggers jshint in the console are printed hints and at the end is printed:
"118 errors in 30 files"

Here is one [example](https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1576/23580727043_25c7331c61.jpg)

How I can find a file where this problem is found?
Is there a way to configure jshint to specify source file responsible for each error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the [`reporter`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint#reporter) option, to modify the plugin's output.

By default (when `reporter` value is `null`), the output is like -

[image]

Switching to `checkstyle` reporter, will give an output like -

[image]

Switching to `jslint` reporter, will give an output like -

[image]

Other than this, you can use custom reporters as well, for example the `jshint-stylish` -

[image]

The grunt task configuration would be -

```
jshint: {
            all: ['entry.js'],
            options: {
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            }
        }
```

You can find other custom reporters at - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=jshint%20reporter